HASH_MISMATCH Azure to GCS Google Transfer Service
Moving data files from ADLS Gen2 to GCS using Google Tranfer Service.
For some set of files, getting repeated error
blobName: "2024-06-18T05.33.11Z/Metadata/1.csv"
errorMessage: "Permanent error, with a last message of Provided MD5 hash "<hash>" doesn't match calculated MD5 hash "<hash1>.; Failed to upload object to GCS."
errorType: "HASH_MISMATCH"
statusCode: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Checked if the files are getting written but those are not modified in ADLS. The same file is written each day in ADLS with a incremented folder date time.
The Hash of the file on ADLS remains same since the file hasn't changed but the logs for the next file in GCP shows a different HASH even different to the previous run.
I am assuming the GCP is also considering the absolute path when generating the MD5.
But this issue should arise for other sets of files also but they are getting copied and hash is matching.
Any idea on this issue?
Try outs -: Tried changing the When to Overwrite property from When changed to Never. Didn't resolve the problem. Changed to Always but that means the job will always copy all the files which isn't ideal.
